# Angularjs $http service passing facebook access token

Tags: angularjs, http, passport-facebook

I'm implementing fb authentication in my SPA built using MEAN stack. While I've successfully implemented the fb authentication using facebook token passport strategy, I'm facing issues in securing API endpoints. Because for that I need to pass both the authenticated user object and access token in the $http service and I've tried passing access_token as a property of the user object and also as a header property, but I still 401 (Unauthorized error). Below is my code snippet.

Passport documentation says "Authorization: Bearer base64_access_token_string". Should the token be encoded in a base64 format? Pls help.

**server code**

```
app.get('/api/getbikes*',
passport.authenticate('facebook-token',{session: false}),
function(req,res){
    if(req.user){
        console.log('In getbikes api');
    // console.log('req.query :',req.query);
        var msg="";
        ubBike
            .find({cust:req.query._id})
            .populate('cust','email')
            .exec(function(err,bikes){
                res.send(bikes);
                if(err) throw err;
            });
    }
    else
    {
        res.send(401);
    }

});
```

**angular code**

*service*

```
this.getbikes = function(user){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method:"GET",
        url:"http://localhost:3000/api/getbikes",
        params: user,
        headers:{
            Authorization:auth.getAccesstoken()
        }            
    }).then(function successCallback(srresponse){
        deferred.resolve(srresponse.data);
    }, 
        function failureCallback(srresponse){
        $log.error("get bikes http call failed ",srresponse.data);
        deferred.reject(srresponse.data);
    });//$http
    return deferred.promise;
};//getbikes
```

*controller*

```
$scope.fblogin= function(){
        auth.fblogin().then(
                function(response){

                $scope.isAuth = auth.isAuth;
                $scope.usr =auth.getResponseobj();
                $scope.usr.access_token=auth.getAccesstoken();  
                $scope.profpic=auth.profpic;

                bike.getbikes($scope.usr).then(function(response){

                    if (response.length ==0)
                    {
                    $location.path('/addbike');//redirect to addbike screen    
                    }
                    else{
                    $location.path('/appoint');//else redirect to view appointment screen
                    }
                },function(reason){
                    $scope.msg1 = reason;
                });//getbikes


            },function(reason){
                 $log.log("fblogin() - failure :Need to login to the application :"+reason);
            })

        };//fblogin
```

Comment: If you're sending the accesstoken in http header, then it should be in this format `Authorization: Bearer accesstokenstring`. Does your header authorization form that way?. Also in your controller you're sending `$scope.usr` not `user`. Please check that as well.

Comment: Also try debugging your server code and find out what does your `req` object contains?

Comment: @Karthik, What does "Bearer accesstokenstring" format mean?Thats where I was stuck initially. Does this mean prefixing the token with 'Bearer'. pls clarify

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18752897/1210896. That's how we send the Authorization information as part of HTTP header for an API request.

Comment: Thanks I was able to encode the token after injecting base64 dependency and $base64 service .I dont get the 401 (unauthorized) error anymore. But I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) and node log gives the following error. InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile
    at D:\Raj\important\youbike\node_modules\passport-facebook-token\lib\index.j
s:155:32
    at passBackControl (D:\Raj\important\youbike\node_modules\passport-facebook-
token\node_modules\passport-oauth\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oaut
h\lib\oauth2.js:123:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>

Comment: Did you check this - Also in your controller you're sending `$scope.usr` not `user`. Please check that as well. ?

Comment: thats fine, because the variable $scope.usr is local only to controller and in service I've defined it as user.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, when I send the header as "Authorization: Bearer access_token_string" ie the fb token as is without base64 encoding the API authentication works perfectly fine. This is contrary to the passport facebook token documentation https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token