# Using oauth2.0 tokens with R's httr package

Tags: r, curl, oauth, oauth-2.0, httr

## Problem

The package `httr` provides CURL wrappers in R (see [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf)).

I'm brand new to HTTP and APIs. My trouble is getting oauth2.0 authentication to work. I have tried various syntax and get either errors or status 401.

**What is the correct way to use an oauth2.0 token and make a `GET()` request using `httr`?**

## Code Attempts

```
# Set UP
  
  url = "https://canvas.{institution}.edu/api/v1/courses"
  key = "{secret_key}"

# 1
  GET(url, sign_oauth2.0(key)) 
  # Error: Deprecated: supply token object to config directly

# 2
  GET(url, config(sign_oauth2.0 = key)) 
  # unknown option: sign_oauth2.0

# 3
  GET(url, config = list(sign_oauth2.0 = key)) 
  # Status 401
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Solution

In this particular use case—working with the [Canvas API](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/index.html)—additional information is required in the *header* of the request.

Using the `GET` function from the `httr` R package, use the `add_header` parameter to supply the argument including your oauth2 key.

Use Option 1 if you don't want to hard code your key into the request (recommended). Or, use Option 2 and insert the key as a string. But in both cases,  "Bearer " precedes the key.

```
# Set Up
url = "https://canvas.{institution}.edu/api/v1/courses"
key = "{secret_key}"

# OPTION 1
GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", key, sep = " ")))

# OPTION 2
courses.request = GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = "Bearer {secret_key}"))
```

#Further Explanations

- Explanation of [Authorization Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068892/oauth-2-0-authorization-header)
- Rationale for why ["Bearer "](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re) must go before the key.
- The [OAuth Bible](http://oauthbible.com/) is useful for understanding components of a request

*Can anyone else explain other reasons why the OP's examples **didn't** work?*

Comment: Note: you don't need `sep = " "` in option 1.