# Connecting ZOHO Analytics and R

Tags: r, zoho

How do I connect Zoho Analytics to R such that I can retrieve data from ZOHO into R?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are 3 parts that you will need to read about to step through connecting Zoho Analytics to RStudio:

1 - **Zoho Analytics-API Authentication**.
The explains how to set up a Zoho Analytics API token.
https://www.zoho.com/analytics/api/v2/#oauth

2 - **R library for API calls: httr**

```
install.packages(c("httr"))
library(httr)
```

Here is the `httr` documentation site:
https://httr.r-lib.org/articles/quickstart.html

Here is the good example by [Danielle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7983039/danielle) of using an oauth token with httr:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45339269/14250642
For your use case, replace, `"{secret_key}"` with the Zoho oauth token that you set up in part one.

3 - **The Zoho Analytics API**
https://www.zoho.com/analytics/api/v2/